# Angular 2: Emit events across multiple components, not just the immediate parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

This is about Angular 2:

How do I access an emitted event from more than one component away? I'm emitting the event from the bottom component and can see it in the mid-level component, but not the top-level one.

[image: Angular 2 components]

Answer (score 2):

You can create Service and provide it in application bootstrap. Then, you can subscribe for changes, or emit message from any other component.

```
import { MessageService} from "./service";
bootstrap(App, [
 MessageService,
])
```

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/d4jIDQ4lSuXUDttKFAS6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a general pub sub service that you could try:

I am using Subjects in order to emit and observe custom events:

```
    import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
    import {Customer} from './customer';

    export class CustomerEventEmitter extends Subject<Customer>{

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        emit(value) { super.next(value); }
    }
```

[More details](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/pub-sub-in-angular-2.0)

[Live demo](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/pub-sub)